# Аналитика сайта без передачи информации сторонним сервисам

Tags: google-analytics, поиск-библиотек

Какие существуют решения для аналитики сайта без передачи данных сторонним сервисам (Yandex, Google, ...) или что нужно гуглить, чтобы их найти? (Anonymous site analytics и internal site analytics не дают нужных результатов)

Comment: Если "аналитика" в данном контексте - это _кто, на какие страницы, сколько раз в час/сутки заходил_, то логи веб-севера сложенные, например, в elasticsearch самое то.

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, вам подойдёт [Matomo Analytics](https://matomo.org/), это бывший piwiki.

Comment: День добрый. А можете кратко описать плюс/минусы?

Comment: Собственно, то что это открытое приложение, которое устанавливается на собственные сервера и собирает статистику, аналогичную GA/ЯМ, является киллер-фичей. Все остальное перечислять не имеет смысла так же, как и пригалать ссылку - приложение развивается и список будет меняться.

Answer (score 0):

Смотря на чём сделан сайт.

Если в основе лежит какая-то CMS (WordPress, Jommla, Bitrix, ModX, etc...), то можно посмотреть соответствующие плагины для них. Например Slimstat для WordPress или JRealtime Analytics для Joomla.

Если какой-то фреймворк, то также можно поискать модули, реализующие подобный функционал. Пример - yii2-analytics для Yii2 (нашёл по запросу: yii2 плагин аналитики сайта).

Даже если сайт сделан на каком-нибудь ASP.NET или Spring MVC, то и в этом случае наверняка можно найти какие-то готовые решения.

В крайнем случае, никто не запрещает написать своё.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно забивать "open-source", тогда это часто будет означать установку на собственном сервере и хранение данных там же, без доступа к ним чужих людей. Это, как правило, фреймоворк-независимо (ну так несколько строчек JS для отправки запроса со страницы).

https://medevel.com/best-20-open-source-free-self-hosted-web-analytics/